# SQL Server print multiple time the same value case when - then distinct doesn't helps

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

> For the database with money transactions being recorded not more than
>   once a day, calculate the total cash balance of all buy-back centers.

So the solution of the problem above is

```
select distinct
    ((select sum(inc) from income_o) - (select sum(out) from outcome_o))
```

and the solution works good. However, I need to check if in the tables the records is present so I introduce case when then statement in my solution.

```
select CASE 
    when (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM income_o) = 0 
    then 0
    when (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM outcome_o) = 0 
    then 0
    else (select distinct ((select sum(inc) from income_o) - (select sum(out) from outcome_o)))
    end as result 
from income_o
```

And after that I get duplicated results:

```
myResult
-----------
28985.9600
28985.9600
28985.9600
28985.9600
28985.9600
28985.9600
28985.9600
28985.9600
28985.9600
```

What I need to receive

```
28985.9600
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Use the `DISTINCT` modifier on the main select... `SELECT DISTINCT CASE...etc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this in subquery and do distinct outside as below:

```
select distinct result from
(
    select CASE 
        when (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM income_o) = 0 
        then 0
        when (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM outcome_o) = 0 
        then 0
        else (select distinct ((select sum(inc) from income_o) - (select sum(out) from outcome_o)))
        end as result 
    from income_o
) a
```

or you can do distinct of case value as well

```
select distinct CASE 
    when (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM income_o) = 0 
    then 0
    when (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM outcome_o) = 0 
    then 0
    else (select distinct ((select sum(inc) from income_o) - (select sum(out) from outcome_o)))
    end as result 
from income_o
```

Comment: Tip: When checking for the existence of one or more rows it is more efficient to use [`EXISTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) rather than getting an exact [`COUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) and then just checking if it is zero, e.g. `when not exists ( select 42 from income_o ) then 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You will get right result after you remove 'from income_o', otherwise the result will show the same number of rows with income_o

```sql
select CASE 
    when (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM income_o) = 0 
    then 0
    when (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM outcome_o) = 0 
    then 0
    else (select distinct ((select sum(inc) from income_o) - (select sum(out) from outcome_o)))
    end as result
```